# I just can't understand Groovy types with Java mindset

Tags: java, generics, groovy

I am struggling to comprehend why code which in Java works, then fails in groovy. For example:

I've found that if I use `Tuple2.of(...` I will get a compilation error, but `new Tuple2(..` works. Why?

```
    static Stream<Tuple2<LocalDate, Double>> forecastEachMonth(Tuple2<LocalDate, Double> openingBalance, Double rate){

        Stream<Tuple2<LocalDate, Double>> stream = Stream.iterate(
                openingBalance,
                {

                    LocalDate current = it.first
                    LocalDate nextDate = it.first.plusMonths(1)

                    int days = Days.daysBetween(current, nextDate).days
                    double years = days / 365.0
                    double interest = it.second * rate * years
                    double nextBalance = it.second + interest

                    // return Tuple2.of(nextDate, nextBalance) // exception after 2 iterations, Have no idea why.
                    return new Tuple2(nextDate, nextBalance)
                }
        )
        return stream
    }
```

You can test this out:

```
        Stream<Tuple2<LocalDate,Double>> test = forecastEachMonth(
                        LocalDate.now(),
                        200000.0d,
                0.05d
        )
        println test.limit(200).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Gives an error:

```
Expected earlier checking to detect generics parameter arity mismatch
Expected: groovy.lang.Tuple<E> 
Supplied: groovy.lang.Tuple<org.joda.time.LocalDate,java.lang.Double>
```

But Intellij knows the correct type when I hover over the local variable.

I've also converted the project to Java and it just works. Which severely plagues my experience coding in Groovy, as I lose heaps of time on code which works in Java but not in Groovy. (Albeit there is no Tuple in Java I just used another library having the collection Pair). But I just can't get my head around why Groovy suddenly doesn't know the type of a given variable, reverts to Object, then just throws an exception, how is that desirable?

Comment: What's the groovy+java version?

Comment: "I've found that if I use Tuple2.of(... I will get a compilation error" - It would be good to know what the compilation error is, and where you expect that method to be coming from.

Comment: Please see update if necessary, note though Java version doesn't have Tuple, but issue is more in that I wouldn't expect semantics such as that to completely wreck my code, and then costs me heaps of time tracking down issue. I'd love to understand why Groovy is doing what it's doing.

Comment: Where did you find Typle2.of method? There's no such method in groovy doc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't understand your "java" pain.

the following code sample works well even with compile static:

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def f(){
  Tuple2<Date, Double> a = new Tuple2(new Date(), 1)
  Tuple2<Date, Double> b = new Tuple2(new Date(), 2)

  List<Tuple2<Date, Double>> list = [a,b]
  List<Tuple2<Date, Double>> result = list.takeWhile{Tuple2<Date, Double> e-> e.getV2()<2}

  assert result instanceof List
  assert result.size()==1
  assert result[0].getV2()<2
  assert result[0] instanceof Tuple2
}

f()
```

### your questions:

> I've found that if I use `Tuple2.of(...` I will get a compilation error, but `new Tuple2(..` works. Why?

there is not such method `Tuple2.of(...` in [Tuple2 class](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Tuple2.html)

> why Groovy suddenly doesn't know the type of a given variable, reverts to Object, then just throws an exception, how is that desirable?

i used your code with minimal changes to make it runnable and it works without any error:

```
import java.time.*
import java.util.stream.*

static Stream<Tuple2<LocalDate, Double>> forecastEachMonth(Tuple2<LocalDate, Double> openingBalance, Double rate){

    Stream<Tuple2<LocalDate, Double>> stream = Stream.iterate(
            openingBalance,
            {

                LocalDate current = it.first
                LocalDate nextDate = it.first.plusMonths(1)

                int days = nextDate - current
                double years = days / 365.0
                double interest = it.second * rate * years
                double nextBalance = it.second + interest

                return new Tuple2(nextDate, nextBalance)
            }
    )
    return stream
}


Stream<Tuple2<LocalDate,Double>> test = forecastEachMonth(
    new Tuple2(LocalDate.now(),200000.0d),
    0.05d
)
println test.limit(200).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: I have updated now you'll see that if you run my method, you'll find `it` goes from a Tuple to an Object. Would love to know why. Note I'm use Jodatime here.

Comment: Method creates a Stream of a bank accounts future value each month given an interest rate with interest compounding monthly, hopefully makes sense.

Comment: tried your code - works well

Comment: You need to change the return to:
`return Tuple2.of(nextDate, nextBalance)` You'll find it errors after the second iteration.

Comment: i have error on first iteration: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static groovy.lang.Tuple2.of() is applicable for argument types: (java.time.LocalDate, Double) values: [2023-01-10, 200849.315068]`. what is the error message do you see? again - there is no `Tuple2.of()` function, however it's possible to define it in some library like this: `Tuple2.metaClass.static.of = {a,b-> new Tuple2(a,b)}`.

Comment: Ok @daggett, I know see what the issue was. Tuple extends AbstractList implements List, which does have the method `of` in it. So Tuple does also have this method. It's signature is `<E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2)` so if your arguments are different types you'd get a compile error, I didn't have `@TypeChecked`. Good to track down the issue, but I did end up ditching groovym don't really have the time to track down this stuff when it happens.

Comment: That's why I asked you about java/groovy version. But you ignored it )

Comment: I'm sorry daggett! I will accept your answer and upvote you, A for effort keep up the good stuff haha. But yeah I didn't really get productivity gains with Groovy, might try it again in the future, but at the moment without IDE holding my hand I struggle.